# Read email type of text/html

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, html-email, javax

How to read email type of "text/html" ?

This is how I get emails:

```
    try {
        store = emailSession.getStore(mailStoreType);
        store.connect(host, username, password);
        Message[] messages = getMessages(folder);
        Message message = messages[emailIndex];
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: This will help you ; https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#mainbody

Comment: @newuserua_ext Thank you :)